# MvcScaffolding one-many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm using MVC 4, EF 4.3 and the MVCScaffolding package.

I have following simple model classes

```
 public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

I scaffolded out the controllers like so:

```
Scaffold Controller Category -Force 
Scaffold Controller Product -Force
```

This generated the controllers/views etc.

Per [Steve sanderson's post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/28/mvcscaffolding-one-to-many-relationships/) I would think that the _CreateOrEdit.cshtml for the Product would contain a dropdown for the Category but it does not.

Followng are the contents of the _CreateOrEdit.cshtml and it does not contain any html template for the Category

```
<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you also need to have a property CategoryID on your Product class. It won't be virtual because you want EntityFramework to persist it in the DB as the foreign key.

Try adding it and scaffold them again to see if it gives you the drop down. You're right in thinking it should.

Also convention is that ID fields will be keys so I don't think you need the [Key] attributes.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure now. Check the tutorial again and see the state of the original models he creates. He has TeamID. He then goes on to add the virtual items Team and the collection of Players. You've replaced your CategoryID with Category. Or you didn't have CategoryID foreign key to start with.

Comment: Looks like this is an inherent limitation of MvcScaffolding.The thing I dislike here is that if you expose the CategoryID on the model and also have a virtual Category property you have to ensure that both are in sync.