# MVC with EF: Scaffold DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, scaffolding

**What I'm trying to do**
Automatically scaffold my Controller and Views based on my Model.

**The Problem**
My DropDownLists (a SelectedItemList) doesn't appear, instead I get a NumericUpDown element.

**The Relation**
A 'Bekroning' can have one 'Bekroner'.
A 'Bekroner' can 'bekroon' many 'Bekroningen'.

**The Model**

```
public class Bekroning
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Omschrijving{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Bekroner_ID { get; set; }
}

public class Bekroner
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Naam { get; set; }
}
```

**Similar Questions**
[MVC 5 Code First scaffolding with simple relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046102/mvc-5-code-first-scaffolding-with-simple-relationship)
[MvcScaffolding one-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100332/mvcscaffolding-one-many-relationship)

But I can't get my head around it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: First you editing data, so always use a view model (do not use data models in your view). And forget scaffolding for dropdownlists - it generates bad code.

Comment: And you have not created your navigation properties for he relationship between the models